# Openwrt - Routing between two broadband connections

Tags: router, openwrt

I am about to have a Virgin media 152 mb line installed, but I also have a standard adsl line (that runs at about 1mbit - which makes bonding them superfluous)

The ADSL line is part of a package that makes it as good as free, but it seems a waste to simply relegate it to being unused.

The plan is to have the ADSL router, and the virgin router plugged into a TP-Link archer c7 (AC1750) router running openwrt. So Virgin will be at 192.168.0.1 and adsl at 192.168.0.2

My first thought is to simply have it as a backup route, how would I implement that using openwrt (this is also the dhcp server)

Is it possible to specify which route different mac addresses are routed through? So laptop goes through the fast link and audio equipment uses the slower one for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The Archer C7 is not a dual-WAN router:
http://www.tp-link.com/sa/products/details/cat-9_Archer-C7.html#specifications

So you will only be able to plug one internet service into it at a time, as far as I can see.

The other questions don't really make sense in this context.

Comment: It is an Archer C7 running OpenWRT, whihc makes it a router with a five port managed switch that can be configured to do whatever you want with.